# Бот для телеграм на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я написал бота, который при вводе команды /start начинает в бесконечном цикле отсылать мне определенный ответ. Бота я задеплоил на хероку, то есть он должен работать постоянно, но раз в день мне приходится заново прописывать команду /start, чтобы он снова начал работать. Я не могу понять, почему он выходит из цикла "while(True)".

Comment: В боте есть база данных?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin , нет, базы данных нет.

Comment: а код можно увидеть? Вы можете редактировать вопрос

Comment: Код бота своего, отредактируйте вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. При деплое на хероку, он автоматически перезапускает скрипт раз в день. Поскольку цикл начитает работать только при вводе команды /start, я просто убрал хендлер на команду и вынес бесконечный цикл в основную часть программы. Тогда при автоматическом перезапуске на хероку, вводить команду или делать что-либо ещё не нужно и при этом код будет выполняться корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего, процесс приложения падает и перезапускается.
Если вам нужен непрерывно спамящий бот, то можно эту проблему решить следующим образом. В любой БД запоминать кому бот начал спамить и при запуске бота возобновлять спам.

Comment: на хероку записи бд при рестарте стираются.

Comment: Ну значит нужно использовать другой хостинг для БД